# SignalR stop "old" connections

Tags: asp.net, sockets, iis, signalr, signalr-hub

I am facing an issue with old SignalR connections. The workflow is like this:

1. Debugging a web project in VS2015, SignalR creates some websockets which send data (status information and data). Nothing fancy.
2. I change some code parts, rebuild the project and load the web project again (in a new tab, old tab still exists).
3. An initialization method gets called in the code (setting some database connection strings, loading values, ...)

Here is my problem: Just before #3 happens (database connection strings are not initialized yet, ...) an websocket poll comes from the old chrome tab. The poll tries to get some data. Application crashes because the initialization isn't done yet - database connection cannot be made yet, and so on.

How would you handle this? Simply use more "if-initialization-is-done-then-..." statements? Or is there a neat trick to handle this in SignalR?

Comment: Where is your initialization code getting called from? What event triggers it?

Comment: When the project starts (eg. localhost:port loads) it triggers a function in the code.

Comment: That's too general. Specifically what event within the ASP.NET lifecycle runs your initialization code?

Comment: Alright, sorry. The initialization happens in the FilterConfig.cs, OnAuthorization method ( the first page is a login page, so it will be triggered if the user clicks on the "Login"-Button.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470545(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: That's not a good place for it. You should run the initialization code when the application starts, such as the Application_Start event in your global application class (global.asax.cs, global.asax.vb or global.asax)

Comment: Alright, gonna take move that. But it will not fix the problem, does it? When the "old" websocket connection tries to connect to the "new", not-initialized host, it will fail again - or am I wrong?

Comment: If you run your initialization early enough in your application's lifecycle, then by the time the SignalR connects, the initialization will be already done.

Comment: Hmm, not quite sure if I explained it good enough. Imagine a websocket#Build1 that polls 24/7, every second. When I start the project with some changes (#Build2), the websocket#Build1 tries to connect to the project#Build2 immediately - even before the initialization in #Build2 happend.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. You need to perform the initialization early enough in the applications lifecycle that by the time it starts accepting SignalR connections, the initialization has already been done. Satisfy your dependencies in the correct order.